# can't play mp3 with j2me SDK 3.0 emulator built-in NetBean 6.9.1

Tags: java-me, mp3

I have try this code but it not work with ClamshellCldcPhone1 (MIDP 2.1, CLDC 1.1)
With "pattern.mid" file it work but with "s.mp3" file it didn't
I known ,The Player has **load data** of (s.mp3) **but not play**,
I have put **s.mp3** int package "audio" , size of s.mp3 is less than 1MB.
Can any one help me?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.MediaException;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.VolumeControl;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author tqwer
 */
public class PlayMp3 extends MIDlet {
    Display display = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Player player = null;
    VolumeControl volumeControl = null;
    public PlayMp3() throws IOException, MediaException {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        display.setCurrent(new Form("form"));
        if(1==1) { 
        inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/s.mp3");
        player = Manager.createPlayer(inputStream, "audio/mpeg");
        }else{    inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/pattern.mid");
        player = Manager.createPlayer(inputStream, "audio/midi");
        }
        player.realize();
        player.prefetch();

         volumeControl  = (VolumeControl)player.getControl("VolumeControl");
            volumeControl.setLevel(100);
            player.start();
            volumeControl  = (VolumeControl)player.getControl("VolumeControl");
            volumeControl.setLevel(100);
            try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream = null;
    }
    public void startApp() {

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

Comment: me tooo .. have the ame problem.... the emulator play's wav file but do not play .mp3 files...